# Kendo Chart issue in IE Only

Tags: internet-explorer, kendo-dataviz

Please can you take a look at this screenshot

[image]

Even though the charts in both browsers have the same number of points the Internet Explorer version is not populated, its as though the bars have been treated as hourly

The data goes from 01/11/2014 - 30/11/2011 23:59

Has anyone ever seen this?  It works fine in Chrome

I am using Twitter Bootstrap but I dont think that is causing the issue

Comment: I'm seeing that the right-half appears if I mouse-over click the left half. Are you seeing the same?

Comment: Thats strange, no I hadnt seen that makes it even nastier to diagnose!  I will see about turning off/changing animation

Comment: The issue is to do with the animation, I will have to try to raise this with Telerik.  I have turned animation off for now and will update this with the fix.